# LibGdx: проблема с прозрачностью при создании скриншота

Tags: java, libgdx, screenshots

Через стандартный способ - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Taking-a-Screenshot
реализовал создание скриншотов, но в полупрозрачных областях спрайтов полупрозрачными получаются области на скриншотах, кроме того, они белеют, несмотря на цвет фона, настолько, насколько мало значение alpha-канала.

Оригинал:
[image: Оригинал]

Скришнот:
[image: Скришнот]

Скриншот с удалённым alpha-каналом:
[image: Скриншот с удалённым alpha-каналом]

Comment: А как вы убрали альфа канал? для удаления альфканала нужно залить фон, а при накладывание слоёв должно происходить смещение(Blend).

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов На третьем скриншоте видно, что это не помогает. Именно удаление альфа канала. Про смещение прошу поподробней.

Comment: простите я неправильно понял. Я думал проблема с рисованием. Судя по всему у вас артифакты при получение рендертекстуры. На какой платформе тестировали?

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов, на ПК. OS Linux, Windows. На Android не тестировал.